# How to install multiple or two versions of Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a lot of Terraform modules written in Terraform 0.11 using gcp-provider of Terraform and want to upgrade the same to Terraform 0.12.

For this purpose, I need to keep both the versions installed on my system and use the version according to the version the module is written in.

I will go one by one in every module and upgrade the module using `terraform 0.12upgrade` to be compatible with Terraform 0.12 as per [this documentation](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html).

How to safely keep two versions of Terraform in one System?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I achieved this safely following the below steps. Similar steps can be followed to do the same on any Linux distro (making sure you are downloading the compatible binary. Confirm [here](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/))

***NOTE*** Running the following commands as root or sudo user

### Create directories to keep the Terraform binaries

```sh
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/tf
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/tf/11
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/tf/12
```

### Download the binaries for both the versions

1. Download and extract the binary for `Terraform 0.11` in a separate directory:

   ```sh
   $ cd /usr/local/tf/11
   $ wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.14/terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip
   $ unzip terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip
   $ rm terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip
   ```
2. Download and extract the binary for `Terraform 0.12` in a separate directory:

   ```sh
   $ cd /usr/local/tf/12
   $ wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.20/terraform_0.12.20_linux_amd64.zip
   $ unzip terraform_0.12.20_linux_amd64.zip
   $ rm terraform_0.12.20_linux_amd64.zip
   ```
3. Create symlinks for both the Terraform versions in `/usr/bin/` directory:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/tf/11/terraform /usr/bin/terraform11
   ln -s /usr/local/tf/12/terraform /usr/bin/terraform12

   # Make both the symlinks executable
   chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/terraform*
   ```

### Calling different versions

- Now, command `terraform11` invokes version 0.11 and `terraform12` invokes version 0.12
- Example:

  ```
  $ terraform11
  $ terraform12
  ```

***NOTE***

- Keeping the binaries in separate directories helps to separate their plugins as well without disturbing each other.

Answer (score 20):

I'd highly recommend the [tfenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv) tool. It sanely and easily can be used to manage multiple terraform installations. It's familiar if you've ever used nvm (for nodejs) or rvm (for ruby).

You can even add a `.terraform-version` file to your modules and the tool will automatically switch terraform versions for you when you `cd` into a module.

Comment: For the doubters out there, this really works! A simple `brew install tfenv` enables you to do something like `tfenv install min-required && tfenv use 0.15.4`. Great for switching between projects easily!

Answer (score 6):

Make your life easy and install [tfswitch](https://github.com/warrensbox/terraform-switcher).  It takes care of installing and switching between versions you need; and it works like a magic.

Answer (score 1):

If using multiple environments with terraform, tfenv would be the best tool to use. I initially had the same error and was able to run `tfenv use version-number` and it solved my issue. For background, I use terraform for personal and work projects on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can also use [tenv](https://github.com/tofuutils/tenv) from OpenTofu. It also still supports Terraform.